# from io import BytesIO ImportError: cannot import name BytesIO

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

when I  try using

```
python "c:\Django\blongo\blongo\blog\manage.py" runserver
```

I get:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 7, in <module>
    from io import BytesIO
ImportError: cannot import name BytesIO
```

Answer (score 43):

try this

```
from io import BytesIO
```

Comment: I am using Python3.6 and this works for me.

Comment: It should work for Python 2.7 too; see https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.BytesIO

Answer (score 5):

Check if there's no your own version of `io.py` using following command.

```
C:\> python -c "import io; print io.__file__"
c:\python27\lib\io.pyc
```

You should see similar output.

If there's your own version, it shadows builtin version of `io` package. Rename your own module with a name that does not collide with standard module. (Don't forget `pyc` files.)

Answer (score -1):

in my case.

import io 
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

Comment: What does this have to do with `BytesIO`?